# facing some issues in my project with the latest version of node

Tags: node.js, node-modules

My project is not executing after updated my node version(updated to these two v8.9.4 and v9.4), can some one help me, is the below listed packages are compatible with the latest node version or not and how to solve this issue.
my package.json:

```
    {
      "name": "v2",
      "version": "0.0.0",
      "private": true,
      "scripts": {
        "start": "nodemon -e html,css,js -i node_modules bin/server.js"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "async": "^1.4.2",
        "aws-sdk": "^2.5.1",
        "body-parser": "~1.12.4",
        "bson": "^0.4.23",
        "compression": "^1.5.2",
        "connect-mongo": "~0.8.2",
        "cookie-parser": "~1.3.5",
        "debug": "~2.2.0",
        "email-existence": "^0.1.5",
        "express": "^4.12.4",
        "express-session": "~1.11.3",
        "fb": "^1.1.1",
        "gm": "^1.18.1",
        "html-pdf": "^2.0.1",
        "image-size": "^0.5.0",
        "jimp": "^0.2.24",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^7.0.1",
        "mailcomposer": "^3.10.0",
        "mailgun": "^0.5.0",
        "mailgun-js": "^0.7.10",
        "mime": "^1.3.4",
        "moment": "^2.13.0",
        "mongodb": "^1.4.38",
        "mongoskin": "^1.4.13",
        "morgan": "~1.5.3",
        "multer": "^1.0.3",
        "node-schedule": "^1.1.1",
        "nodemailer": "v0.7.1",
        "paperwork": "^2.1.1",
        "paypal-rest-sdk": "^1.6.8",
        "qs": "^4.0.0",
        "quick-pay": "^1.2.0",
        "serve-favicon": "~2.2.1",
        "sharp": "^0.15.1",
        "swig": "^1.4.2",
        "underscore": "^1.8.3"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "request": "^2.58.0",
        "striptags": "^2.0.2"
      }
    }
```

have added my server.js below, till v7 it is fine.
    server.js

```
var app = require('../app');
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);
server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

function normalizePort(val) {
    var port = parseInt(val, 10);

    if (isNaN(port)) {
        // named pipe
        return val;
    }

    if (port >= 0) {
        // port number
        return port;
    }

    return false;
}

function onError(error) {
    if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
        throw error;
    }

    var bind = typeof port === 'string' ? 'Pipe ' + port : 'Port ' + port;

    switch (error.code) {
        case 'EACCES':
            console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
            process.exit(1);
            break;
        case 'EADDRINUSE':
            console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
            process.exit(1);
            break;
        default:
            throw error;
    }
}


function onListening() {
    var addr = server.address();
    var bind = typeof addr === 'string' ? 'pipe ' + addr : 'port ' + addr.port;
    console.log('Listening on ' + bind);
    if (fs.existsSync('/code/resTest/test/index.js')) {
        console.log('touching marker');
        fs.writeFileSync("/code/resTest/test/marker.js", '');
    }
}
```

Comment: share your server.js file content, so people can help you

Comment: @moeinrahimi updated :)

Comment: Are you getting any specific error when you attempt to run this with node?

Comment: @Brightstar  none of the api's are running, in postman it is only saying `could not get any response` but in previous versions it was fine.

Comment: OK... I'm afraid I don't use or know how to use postman. Normally if node processes refuse to execute they throw errors. I've never seen it fail silently. Wish I could be of help.

Comment: what is ../app ?